# return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename)); Specified Module not found

Tags: tensorflow

[Getting Error while executing tensorflow project in NodeJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKuNt.png)

Hi I am getting above error while executing the node js tensor flow project.
find my github url below.

https://github.com/veerabrahmam952/TRecommendation

I have installed build tools and tried as much as possible solutions but nothing worked out

I have installed tensorlow in NodeJS.
then executed 'npm install' command then getting above error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.